# issue with custom directive for checking unique email id

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive

I am working on Angularjs form where i need to validate whether input value is on database or not.
my html is as below

```
<div class="form-group mg-btm0" show-errors>
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4 fw-norm txt-right">Email ID:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email ID" name="emailAddress" ng-required="true" autocomplete="Off" ng-model="User.emailId"
                        ng-maxlength="100" emailid-available-validator>
                    <span class="help-block" ng-if="RegisterUser.emailAddress.$error.email">A valid email is required.</span>
                    <span class="help-block" ng-if="RegisterUser.emailAddress.$error.maxlength">Max length is 100.</span>
                    <span class="help-block" ng-if="RegisterUser.emailAddress.$pending"> Checking emailId...</span>
                    <span class="help-block" ng-if="RegisterUser.emailAddress.emailidAvailable">EmailId entered has already been registered</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Directive is as below

```
angularFormsApp.directive('emailidAvailableValidator', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.emailidAvailable = function (value) {
                //var emailid = { 'emailid': emailaddress };
                return $http.get(baseurl + "Users/CheckExternalUserExists/", { emailid: value });
            };
        }
    }
}])
```

and controller is as below

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CheckExternalUserExists(string emailid)
        {
            if (AccountExecutor.UserExists(emailid))
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Exists");
            }
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Not Exists");
        }
```

Now problem I am having are.

1 . Email id being pass as `null` to controller.

2 . I want to show two message

a) If email id is unique , then message should say its unique something

b) if email id exists then It should show message that it exists ,
   currently message is not being display only red border is showing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try below in your code

  ngModel.$asyncValidators.emailidAvailable = function (ngModel.$modelValue)  {
            //var emailid = { 'emailid': emailaddress };
            return $http.get(baseurl + "Users/CheckExternalUserExists/", { emailid: value });
        };

  check out below link for more information...
    [asyncValidators][1]
```

Comment: how its different ??